# How to remove cell padding in table

Tags: html, css, angular, html-table, cellpadding

I'm building betting application using angular 12. I have problem utilizing space in cells. Namely there is a lot of cell padding that wastes space.

```
<table class="w-100 text-white">
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let match of data; let index=index" app-match-row [match]="match"
        [ngClass]="{'even':index%2==0,'odd':index%2!=0}"></tr>
</tbody>
```

and here is app-match-row code:

```
<td cellpadding="0" class="align-middle different-text text-center">{{match.broj}}</td>
<td cellpadding="0" class="align-middle text-center"><img class="w-25" [src]="getSportIcon()"></td>
<td cellpadding="0" class="align-middle different-text text-center">{{getThirdColumnData()}}</td>
<td cellpadding="0" class="align-middle" [ngSwitch]="match.sh_sport.sh_sport_id">
    <app-info-football *ngSwitchCase="1" [match]="match"></app-info-football>
    <app-info-hockey *ngSwitchCase="2" [match]="match"></app-info-hockey>
    <app-info-basketball *ngSwitchCase="3" [match]="match"></app-info-basketball>
    <app-info-tennis *ngSwitchCase="4" [match]="match"></app-info-tennis>
    <app-info-handball *ngSwitchCase="5" [match]="match"></app-info-handball>
    <app-info-volleyball *ngSwitchCase="7" [match]="match"></app-info-volleyball>
</td>
<td cellpadding="0" [ngSwitch]="match.sh_sport.sh_sport_id">
    <app-first-column-football *ngSwitchCase="1" [match]="match"></app-first-column-football>
    <app-first-column-hockey *ngSwitchCase="2" [match]="match"></app-first-column-hockey>
    <app-first-column-basketball *ngSwitchCase="3" [match]="match"></app-first-column-basketball>
    <app-first-column-tennis *ngSwitchCase="4" [match]="match"></app-first-column-tennis>
    <app-first-column-handball *ngSwitchCase="5" [match]="match"></app-first-column-handball>
</td>
<td cellpadding="0" [ngSwitch]="match.sh_sport.sh_sport_id">
    <app-second-column-football *ngSwitchCase="1" [match]="match"></app-second-column-football>
    <!-- <app-second-column-hockey *ngSwitchCase="2" [match]="match"></app-second-column-hockey> -->
    <app-second-column-basketball *ngSwitchCase="3" [match]="match"></app-second-column-basketball>
    <app-seccond-column-tennis *ngSwitchCase="4" [match]="match"></app-seccond-column-tennis>
</td>
<td cellpadding="0" [ngSwitch]="match.sh_sport.sh_sport_id">
    <app-third-column-football *ngSwitchCase="1" [match]="match"></app-third-column-football>
    <app-third-column-hockey *ngSwitchCase="2" [match]="match"></app-third-column-hockey>
    <app-third-column-basketball *ngSwitchCase="3" [match]="match"></app-third-column-basketball>
    <app-third-column-tennis *ngSwitchCase="4" [match]="match"></app-third-column-tennis>
    <app-third-column-handball *ngSwitchCase="5" [match]="match"></app-third-column-handball>
</td>
<td cellpadding="0" [ngSwitch]="match.sh_sport.sh_sport_id">
    <app-fourth-column-football *ngSwitchCase="1" [match]="match"></app-fourth-column-football>
    <app-fourth-column-hockey *ngSwitchCase="2" [match]="match"></app-fourth-column-hockey>
    <app-fourth-column-tennis *ngSwitchCase="4" [match]="match"></app-fourth-column-tennis>
</td>
```

And here is visual representation of the problem:
[image]

The space specified with red lines is the one I want to remove.

Comment: Tables automatically distribute space evenly and efficiently. To decrease horizontal space, you can make the table narrower. Otherwise you'll just move space from one spot to another. To decrease vertical space in one-line cells, you'll need to make all other cells one line.

Answer (score -2):

`border: 2px solid set-color;` Replace "set-color" with what every color you use and this might help.

Comment: How does this address the question of space?

Comment: @Sean they are talking about the white spaces in the middle right???

Comment: The red lines represents the padding I'm willing to remove.